# Leaflet-geotiff plugin error after compiling Angular app

Tags: angular, leaflet

I faced with problem that after compiling my app based on `Angular 6` I have following error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at main.js:3 and it
>   link to var GeoTIFF = require("./geotiff.js");

In [official documentation](https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff#1-include-the-javascript-file-and-dependencies) said that I should implement followign dependencies to work with leaflet-geotiff plugin:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/geotiff@0.4.1/dist/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/plotty@0.2.0/src/plotty.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet-geotiff.js"></script>
<!-- Load any renderer you need -->
<script src="leaflet-geotiff-plotty.js"></script>
<script src="leaflet-geotiff-vector.js"></script>
```

So I added folowing in my `angular.json`:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
    "node_modules/geotiff/dist/main.js",
    "node_modules/plotty/src/plotty.js",
    "node_modules/leaflet-geotiff/leaflet-geotiff.js",
    "node_modules/leaflet-geotiff/leaflet-geotiff-plotty.js"
]
```

If I remove `"node_modules/geotiff/dist/main.js"` error disapears. Maybe I implement with wrong way? How to solve this problem?

**Update** I also added `@types/node` but it didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the provided example it appears everything is fine with referencing  `leaflet-geotiff` plugin library and its dependencies except the line: `"node_modules/geotiff/dist/geotiff.js"`. For Angular application `node_modules/geotiff/dist/geotiff.browserify.js` needs to be imported instead.

There is one more point regarding `leaflet-geotiff` documentation, it does not seem to be very accurate in terms of which parameters are mandatory for geoTIFF layer, for example `renderer` property appears to be mandatory, without providing it the following error is getting displayed:

> Cannot read property 'render' of null

Here is an example on how component for displaying geoTIFF raster data might look like:

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-map",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    const map = L.map("map").setView([-33, 147], 6);
    L.tileLayer("https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
      maxZoom: 8,
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    const windSpeed = LeafletGeotiff.leafletGeotiff(
      "https://stuartmatthews.github.io/leaflet-geotiff/tif/wind_speed.tif",
      {
        band: 0,
        name: "Wind speed",
        renderer2: new LeafletGeotiff.LeafletGeotiff.Plotty({
          displayMin: 0,
          displayMax: 30,
          arrowSize: 20,
          clampLow: false,
          clampHigh: true,
          colorScale: "rainbow"
        })
      }
    ).addTo(map);

    const windDirection = LeafletGeotiff.leafletGeotiff(
      "https://stuartmatthews.github.io/leaflet-geotiff/tif/wind_direction.tif",
      {
        band: 0,
        name: "Wind direction",
        renderer: new LeafletGeotiff.LeafletGeotiff.VectorArrows({
          arrowSize: 20,
          displayMin: 0,
          displayMax: 6,
        })
      }
    ).addTo(map);
  }
}
```

Here is a **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-93zbcz)** (the example is adapted from official [Leaflet geoTIFF demo](https://stuartmatthews.github.io/leaflet-geotiff/) )

> Note: in the provided example libraries are referenced via `ES6`
>   Modules instead of Global scripts

Comment: thank you a lot. Yesterday I did the same way (I mean imported plugin script into component). And it worked. I have one more issue, I'd be glad if you watch it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55610066/leaflet-geotiff-usage-in-angular-6-application