# Leaflet-geotiff usage in Angular 6 application

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet, geotiff

I faced with problem that I can't to display any `.tif` image on my map. I'm using [leaflet-geotiff](https://github.com/stuartmatthews/leaflet-geotiff) plugin for my map. I downloaded the file (for example from [gis-lab.info](http://gis-lab.info/qa/samples.html), here is [link to download](http://gis-lab.info/data/samples/clearcuts_174016_20101018_clip.7z)) and tried to paste and display on my map. But I always get `Custom Mask  is off screen.`

Here is a sample how I use it:

```
import * as geotiff from 'leaflet-geotiff/leaflet-geotiff';
import * as plotty from 'leaflet-geotiff/leaflet-geotiff-plotty';

export class MapComponent {

    ngOnInit() {
        this.map.on('load', () => {
            const options = {
                band: 0,
                name: 'Custom Mask',
                opacity: 1,
                renderer: new plotty.Plotty({
                    colorScale: 'greys'
                })
            };
            new geotiff.LeafletGeotiff('assets/uploads/clearcuts_174016_20101018_clip.tif', options).addTo(this.leafletMap);
        });
    }
}
```

And also here what I have in browser console (I added some `console.log` in `leaflet-geotiff` lib to be sure that tif file parsed there):

[image]

Seems in code in `leaflet-geotiff` it happens when `plotHeight` and `plotWidth` has negative values. And my layer still not showing on map. What am I doing wrong? And how can I display custom tif file correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the error `Custom Mask  is off screen.` occurs since the [provided file](http://gis-lab.info/data/samples/clearcuts_174016_20101018_clip.7z) is represented in [`WGS 84 / UTM zone 39N`](https://epsg.io/32639) projection

[image]

while only `EPSG:4326` files are supported by [`geotiff.js` library](https://github.com/geotiffjs/geotiff.js) (dependency for `leaflet-geotiff`).

From `leaflet-geotiff` readme file:

> url - GeoTIFF file URL. Currently only EPSG:4326 files are supported.

Once reprojected to (e.g. using [this tool](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/GdalWarp)) to `EPSG:4326`, it could be displayed via `leaflet-geotiff` like this

[image]